# Passing a block to a dynamically created method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I'm creating a module that extends the functionality of an ActiveRecord model.

Here's my initial setup.

My class:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_my_modiable
end
```

And Module:

```
module MyMod
  def self.is_my_modiable
    class_eval do 
      def new_method
        self.mod = true
        self.save!
      end
   end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base(extend,MyMod)
```

What I would like to do now is extend the functionality of the `new_method` by passing in a block. Something like this:

```
class MyClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  is_my_modiable do
    self.something_special
  end
end

module MyMod
  def self.is_my_modiable
    class_eval do 
      def new_method
        yield if block_given?
        self.mod = true
        self.save!
      end
   end
  end
end
```

This doesn't work though, and it makes sense. In the class_eval, the new_method isn't being executed, just defined, and thus the yield statement wouldn't get executed until the method actually gets called.

I've tried to assign the block to a class variable within the class_eval, and then call that class variable within the method, but the block was being called on all is_my_modiable models, even if they didn't pass a block into the method.

I might just override the method to get the same effect, but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote them when you accept their answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can solve this by saving passed block to an instance variable on class object and then evaling that in instance methods.

`bl.call` won't do here, because it will execute in the original context (that of a class) and you need to execute it in scope of this current instance.

```
module MyMod
  def is_my_modiable(&block)
    class_eval do
      @stored_block = block # back up block
      def new_method
        bl = self.class.instance_variable_get(:@stored_block) # get from class and execute
        instance_eval(&bl) if bl
        self.mod = true
        self.save!
      end
    end
  end
end

class MyClass
  extend MyMod

  is_my_modiable do
    puts "in my modiable block"
    self.something_special
  end

  def something_special
    puts "in something special"
  end

  attr_accessor :mod
  def save!; end
end

MyClass.new.new_method
# >> in my modiable block
# >> in something special
```

Comment: Thanks. I was getting close. I was calling the block instead of using instance_eval. It seems when I called the block the self inside the block wasn't the instance as I had expected(obviously instance_eval fixed this). My question is, what is self inside the block when bl.call is used instead of instance_eval(&bl). Is this an example of closures, and if so, is it closed over when declared in the class or assigned in the class_eval (@stored_block=block)?

Comment: Block is bound to its lexical context. You create it in context of `MyClass` (the class), so this is the `self`. `instance_eval` rebinds the block.

Comment: In case you want to pass parameters use [instance_exec](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec) instead of [instance_eval](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_eval)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by assigning the block as a method parameter:

```
module MyMod
  def self.is_my_modiable
    class_eval do 
      def new_method(&block)
        block.call if block
        self.mod = true
        self.save!
      end
   end
  end
end
```

Comment: OP wants to pass the block to `is_my_modiable`, not `new_method`.